# How to call it? Declare a father class, assign a child class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

First of all, I am not trying to do anything particular. I know how to do this, it is just that I do not know how is it called.

When you write a code like this:

```
List<Mammal> myAnimals = new List<Mammal>();
myAnimals.Add(new Dog());
myAnimals.Add(new Cat());
```

I want to know if declaring an object of class Mammal and assigining a child class (in this example.. cat or dog) has a name.

To make it a bit clearer on what I am looking for.
I could have a method called `SayHi()` in class Mammal, and override it in class Dog and Cat. I know that is called overriding.

Does what I said first has a special name? is it an attribute from oop?

Comment: That's called `Polymorphism`.

Comment: It's typically called `Parent` class, programming is gender agnostic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The terms you're looking for are [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Added some links to C# programming guides that will further help to explain both topics. And you only mentioned polymorphism

Comment: @HighCore ...and? It's still a correct answer, and you didn't post one yourself.

Comment: I was under the idea that this was just plain polymorphism. But my professor said it was not. But it in the link in polymorphism explains quite directly in the first part. Thanks.

Comment: @bebopayan Feel free to mark it as the answer if you're satisfied with the explanation :)

Comment: @JesseCarter I will, just one quick question. Would you say it's different from covariance or contravariance? [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

Comment: nevermind I came to realize the stupidity of my question :)